# How to only allow 3 numbers on trim inside strlen?

Tags: php, validation, jigoshop

I am using Jigoshop 1.9.3.1 but I have a problem with validating the postcode.

I want customers to only be able to type 3 numbers on postcode field, so I changed the postcode validation PHP code:

`jigoshop_validation.class.php` http://pastebin.com/PwZTyD5w

Postcode check class http://pastebin.com/1B5rLWan

I replaced

```
if ( strlen( trim( preg_replace( '/[\s\-A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $postcode ))) > 0 ) return false;
```

with

```
if ( strlen( trim( preg_replace( '/[\s\-A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $postcode ))) == 0 ) return false;
```

Now customers can't type postcode less than 3 numbers, but can type more than 3 numbers. I want them to be only able to type 3 numbers exactly. How can I do this?

PS. I am not planned to update Jigoshop to the latest version, because of some reasons.

Comment: The line you have quoted is simply a very dumb way to check for invalid characters. Much better to do `if( preg_match('/[^-\sA-Z0-9]/i',$postcode)) return false;`. That aside, you want to look at the `self::$postcode_regex` array and see what you've got there.

Comment: PS. I already enabled postcode validation funtion in Jigoshop Dashboard.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: I was writing the same comment with the word "stupid" instead of "dump".

Comment: use **preg_match()** function **if(preg_match("#^[0-9]{3}#",$postcode))
{echo "code is of 3digits and ok";
else {echo "wrong code";}**